# Vuex payload unique ID repeated twice (or more)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm making a cart system for a shop, and want to add a product to the cart and attach a unique id to it in vuex. Each id is unique to the product instance (i.e. no same product has the same ID, they're completely different)

I add a product like this:

```
...mapActions({ addToCart: 'addToCart' })
```

In Vuex:

```
addToCart: (state, payload) => {
    payload['uniqueId'] = uuid();
    state.cart.push(payload);
},
```

uuid() method:

```
const uuid = () => {
    return ([1e7] + -1e3 + -4e3 + -8e3 + -1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
        (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
    )
}
```

All is good apart from that all products inherit the ID from the newest product added.

`state.cart` is an array of objects.

Also tried this using the npm package uuid, with same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you're using the same variable reference for `payload` when committing the mutation so whenever you change one, you change them all.

The simplest solution is to break the reference. For example, in your store

```js
addToCart: (state, payload) => {
  state.cart.push({
    ...payload, //  using spread syntax breaks the object reference
    uniqueId: uuid()
  })
},
```